# fix detached head after rebase of one repository to another remote repository

Tags: git, rebase

After doing rebase and several `git rebase --continue` I ended up in a detached head.
My goal is to push my local commits in `my-feature` branch in `origin` remote to the `master` branch in `github` remote. Any solution?

Comment: Are you still in a rebase? Has it completed? What does `git status` output?

Comment: it seems the rebase has not finished?! `Last commands done (39 commands done):
   pick 27819caf Add x
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (6 remaining commands):
   pick 461a3190 Add y
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'my-feature' on 'b0c311e8'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)`

Comment: What would you like to do?

Comment: "after rebase" - you are still *in* the rebase. Continue & finish it and you will no longer be in a detached head state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finish the rebase until you don't get `git rebase --continue` in your status.

If still detached, create a temporary branch in the detached location:

```
$ git branch tmp
```

Then push `tmp` to the `master` branch on `github`:

```
$ git push github tmp:master
```